# My odd music teacher

Tags: knowledge, cipher, music

I have a problem, and I need your help! My music teacher is, well, a bit *odd*. Instead of telling me what topic we're going to be quizzed on, he's given me this puzzle to solve instead. He handed me two pieces of paper:

Paper 1:

> DOPHMIDOAEXXDOMILYDOMILYDOMIDODOLOMIDOMIDOIOMIIODOMIDODOAELODOMIMIIOMIIODOIOLODOLOAEDOMIXXDOLOAEDOMIAEIOMIIODOAEDODOAELOIOMIIODOIOMIIOMIIODOAEAEDOAEDODOAELODOAEXXDOLOPH

Paper 2:

> 0. A cat, or a bit like an onion
> 1. A picture of the devil painted by a part of pesto
> 2. A bit similar to the name of a food storage device
> 3. A seller of purple clothing
> 4. A master of rooster+stories
> 5. A visitor from 58tughb
> 6. A thing in need of a key
> 7. A no from you and I

He said that's all I'll need to figure out what I should study for the quiz, but I just can't solve it! Maybe you'll have better luck than me...

Hint:

> He also said that after I finish solving the list, I shouldn't take the answers too literally, but think back to what I've already learnt in class.

---

Note:

> I've added the knowledge tag because it may require some knowledge that isn't considered 'common knowledge', however it is not totally *required* in order to solve the puzzle.

Comment: Is the fact that the list starts at 0 important?

Comment: I haven't figured out the answer yet, but I thought you might be able to use what I've found so far. If you divide the letters on the first paper into pairs, you get 8 different combinations: DO, PH, MI, AE, XX, LY, LO and IO. The lines from paper 2 look like cryptic descriptions to me. 4 might be something along the lines of cocktails or bartender. 6 might be lock, but that might be too easy. 5 leads to a riddle on quizlet.com from 6 years ago, that I haven't solved yet either. The last clue I got from that riddle was that I had to search linlin47 on youtube and find the quizlet riddle video.

Comment: Seeing 8 hints is giving me an indication that it's something to do with the "do-re-mi...." Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @CaelanO'Toole it seems to be, otherwise he would've probably started the list at 1!

Comment: @jaydm26 We haven't learnt solfège in class, so I don't think that's it!

Comment: @KoA could you give us some more hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Paper 1 says

> Toccata and Fugue in D minor

This is decoded using paper 2

> As Anna pointed out, Paper 1 is comprised of 8 different bigrams: DO, PH, MI, AE, XX, LY, LO and IO
>
>  Paper 2 is based on [modern musical modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(music)#Modern)
>
>  0 = IO = A cat, or a bit like an onion = ION(IAN)
>  1 = DO = A picture of the devil painted by a part of pesto = DORIAN (solved by feelinferrety)
>  2 = PH = A bit similar to the name of a food storage device = PHRYGIAN
>  3 = LY = A seller of purple clothing = [LYDIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lydia_of_Thyatira)(N)
>  4 = MI = A master of rooster+stories = MIXOLOGIST / MIXOLYDIAN
>  5 = AE = A visitor from 58tughb = ALIEN / AEOLIAN
>  6 = LO = A thing in need of a key = LOCK / LOCRIAN
>  7 = XX = A no from you and I = XX
>
>  Replacing the bigrams with the digits gives us a simple octal ASCII cipher: `124 157 143 143 141 164 141 040 141 156 144 040 106 165 147 165 145 040 151 156 040 104 040 155 151 156 157 162`

Comment: I was thinking it would go this way once I saw Dorian $\rightarrow$ DO, and figured on XX being an X from each of you and I.

Comment: Very good! Perhaps you can think of some musical explanation for the pairs of letters? (XX not included)

Comment: @KoA Oooh I've got it; that's neat!

Comment: @Will that's right! Number 5 was supposed to be 'Alien' because of the similar sound, not the letters (same as Phrygian/Fridge)

Answer (score 2):

## Partial

A cat, or a bit like an onion

> ?

A picture of the devil painted by a part of pesto

> The portrait of Dorian Gray was painted by Basil Hallward

A bit similar to the name of a food storage device

> Like a Frigidaire or Ziploc or Tupperware?

A seller of purple clothing

> I'm not sure this is it, but ... [The Purple Store](https://www.thepurplestore.com/)?

A master of rooster+stories

> Rooster = cock, stories = tales, a master of cocktails = bartender.

A visitor from 58tughb

Thanks to [Will](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/17147/will) for the better answer...

> This string is an up-to-down listing of the keys 5tgbhu8 (left-to-right) which form an arrow indicating the spacebar, so likely an alien or astronaut.

Following the more complex path leads you on a wild goose chase...

> The string identifies [this quizlet](https://quizlet.com/2498961/58tughb-flash-cards/) with the following message:
>  `hppf kpn og upo ,sfr ot jrtr hp yp yjr erndoyr eee/upiyinr/vp, smf yu[r om ;om;om58 gomf yjr bofrp wiox;ry toff;r`
>
>  which, when decrypted by moving each letter one to the left on the keyboard, translates to:
>  `good job if you made it here go to the website www.youtube.com and type in linlin47 find the video quizlet riddle`
>
>  Which leads you to [this user profile](https://www.youtube.com/user/linlin47) (at the time of posting, no videos can be seen on the profile)

A thing in need of a key

> Could be a lock or a map or a song

A no from you and I

> ?

Comment: I think 58tughb is supposed to be an arrow pointing to "space" (look at your keyboard)

Comment: Nice, @Will. I figured on it being something way easier but couldn't just dismiss the irony of there being a thing out there related to puzzling with exactly that string.